# Huge performance difference between table variables and temp tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, temp-tables, table-variable

I have an `UDF`, providing a bunch of data. Several table variables are used. At this time, no indices are created.

Runtime with testdata is about **30 sec**.

Only changing the table variables into temp tables ( out of the `UDF`, since `#tables` are not allowed ), decreases runtime significantly. It's about **3 seconds**.
This [article](http://sqlserverplanet.com/tsql/yet-another-temp-tables-vs-table-variables-article) explains the differences, but I don't see the point, which is responsible for this kind of performance-delta.

Anyway - temp tables are not allowed in `UDF`, so I could easily use a `SPROC`. Unfortunately I can't, because target "container" for the data has to be a view or a table. **Not changeable** because of third party restrictions. ( data of an erp-system is preprcocessed and has to be provided in a table or view, eg anything you can access via `select <col> from <object>`.

I tried adding an index creating the table variables used at the moment, but runtime didn't decrease.

Any hints or tips to achieve the performace of temp tables while getting data into a view at the end is appreciated.

SQL-Query ( with table variables is added, but demo data can't be provided ):

```
declare  @Results TABLE
(
          "id"                  NVARCHAR( 100 )
        , "oprNum1"             INT
        , "job1Id"              NVARCHAR( 100 )
        , "job1Type"            INT
        , "oprNum2"             INT
        , "job2Id"              NVARCHAR( 100 )
        , "job2Type"            INT
        , "minimumDistance"     INT
        , "maximumDistance"     INT
        , "resourceLocked"      INT
        , "durationLocked"      INT
        , "slot1"               FLOAT
        , "slot2"               FLOAT
        , "color"               BIGINT
        , "origin"              NVARCHAR( 50 )
        , "partition"           BIGINT 
)

    DECLARE @jobs TABLE
    (  
        "rank"              INT
        , "id"              NVARCHAR( 100 )
        , "projectId"       NVARCHAR( 100 )
        , "prodId"          NVARCHAR( 20 )
        , "oprNum"          INT
        , "oprPriority"     INT
        , "jobId"           NVARCHAR( 100 )
        , "jobType"         INT
        , "overlapFactor"   FLOAT
        , "partition"       BIGINT

        , UNIQUE CLUSTERED("rank","prodId","jobid")
    );

    INSERT INTO @jobs
    SELECT
        "rank"              = RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY job."dataAreaId", job."prodId"
                                    , CASE job."oprPriority"
                                        WHEN 0 THEN job."oprPriority" 
                                        ELSE job."oprPriority" / job."oprPriority" 
                                    END
                                ORDER BY job."rank" )
        , "id"              = job."id"
        , "projectId"       = job."projectId"
        , "prodId"          = job."prodId"
        , "oprNum"          = job."oprNum"
        , "oprPriority"     = job."oprPriority"
        , "jobId"           = job."axJobId"
        , "jobType"         = job."jobType"
        , "overlapFactor"   = job."overlapFactor"
        , "partition" = job."partition"
    FROM "dbo"."_company_job" AS job;

    INSERT INTO @Results
    (
          "id"
        , "oprNum1"
        , "job1Id"
        , "job1Type"
        , "oprNum2"
        , "job2Id"
        , "job2Type"
        , "minimumDistance"
        , "maximumDistance"
        , "resourceLocked"
        , "durationLocked"
        , "slot1"
        , "slot2"
        , "color"
        , "origin"
        , "partition"
    )
    SELECT DISTINCT     
          "id"              = Job1."id" + N'_' + Job2."id"
        , "oprNum1"         = Job1."oprNum"
        , "job1Id"          = Job1."id"
        , "job1Type"        = Job1."jobType"
        , "oprNum2"         = Job2."oprNum"
        , "job2Id"          = Job2."id"
        , "job2Type"        = Job2."jobType"
        , "minimumDistance" = 0
        , "maximumDistance" = 0
        , "resourceLocked"  = CASE Job1."oprNum" WHEN Job2."oprNum" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        , "durationLocked"  = 0
        , "slot1"           = Job1."OVERLAPFACTOR"
        , "slot2"           = 0.0
        , "color"           = 0x00FFFFFF
        , "origin"          = 'job'
        , "partition" = Job1."partition"
    FROM @jobs AS Job1
    INNER JOIN @jobs AS Job2
        ON 1 = 1
        AND Job2."partition" = Job1."partition"
        AND Job2."projectId"        = Job1."projectId"
        AND Job2."oprPriority"  = Job1."oprPriority"
        AND Job2."rank"         = Job1."rank" +1
        AND Job2."id"           != Job1."id"
        AND Job2.jobType        NOT IN ( 4 )
    WHERE Job1."oprPriority" = 0
        OR ( Job1."oprPriority" > 0 AND Job1."oprNum" = job2."oprNum" );

    INSERT INTO @Results
    (
          "id"
        , "oprNum1"
        , "job1Id"
        , "job1Type"
        , "oprNum2"
        , "job2Id"
        , "job2Type"
        , "minimumDistance"
        , "maximumDistance"
        , "resourceLocked"
        , "durationLocked"
        , "slot1"
        , "slot2"
        , "color"
        , "origin"
        , "partition"
    )
    SELECT
          "id"              = Job1."id" + N'_' + Job2."id"
        , "oprNum1"         = Job1."oprNum"
        , "job1Id"          = Job1."id"
        , "job1Type"        = Job1."jobType"
        , "oprNum2"         = Job2."oprNum"
        , "job2Id"          = Job2."id"
        , "job2Type"        = Job2."jobType"
        , "minimumDistance" = 0
        , "maximumDistance" = 2147483647
        , "resourceLocked"  = CASE Job1."oprNum" WHEN Job2."oprNum" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        , "durationLocked"  = 0
        , "slot1"           = job2."OVERLAPFACTOR"
        , "slot2"           = 0.0
        , "color"           = 0x000000FF    
        , "origin"          = 'milestone'
        , "partition"       = Job1."partition"
    FROM @jobs AS job1
    INNER JOIN @jobs AS job2
    ON 1 = 1
    AND job2."partition" = job1."partition"
    AND job2."projectId"        = job1."projectId"
        AND Job2."oprPriority"  = Job1."oprPriority"
        AND Job2."rank"         = Job1."rank" +1
        AND Job1."id"           != Job2."id"
        AND Job2.jobType        IN ( 4 );

    INSERT INTO @Results
    (
          "id"
        , "oprNum1"
        , "job1Id"
        , "job1Type"
        , "oprNum2"
        , "job2Id"
        , "job2Type"
        , "minimumDistance"
        , "maximumDistance"
        , "resourceLocked"
        , "durationLocked"
        , "slot1"
        , "slot2"
        , "color"
        , "origin"
        , "partition"
    )
    SELECT
        "id"                = CASE slot."value" 
                                WHEN 0.0
                                    THEN Job1."id" + N'_' + Job2."id"
                                ELSE Job2."id" + N'_' + Job1."id"
                            END
        , "oprNum1"         = Job1."oprNum"
        , "job1Id"          = Job1."id"
        , "job1Type"        = Job1."jobType"
        , "oprNum2"         = Job2."oprNum"
        , "job2Id"          = Job2."id"
        , "job2Type"        = Job2."jobType"
        , "minimumDistance" = 0
        , "maximumDistance" = 0
        , "resourceLocked"  = 0
        , "durationLocked"  = 0
        , "slot1"           = slot."value"
        , "slot2"           = slot."value"
        , "color"           = 0xCCCC00FF
        , "origin"          = N'job'
        , "partition" = Job1."partition"
    FROM @jobs AS Job1
    INNER JOIN @jobs AS Job2
        ON 1 = 1
        AND job2."partition" = job1."partition"
        and  job2."projectId"       = job1."projectId"
        AND job2."oprNum"       = job1."oprNum"
        AND job2."jobType"      = job1."jobType"
        AND Job2."oprPriority"  = job1."oprPriority" +1
        AND Job2."id"           != Job1."id"
    LEFT JOIN @jobs AS prevJob
        ON 1 = 1
        AND prevJob."partition" = job2."partition" 
        AND prevJob."projectId"     =   job2."projectId"
        AND prevJob."rank"          =   job2."rank" -1
        AND prevJob."oprPriority"   =   job2."oprPriority"
        AND prevJob."id"            !=  job2."id"
    INNER JOIN "dbo"."BASEENUMS" AS enums
        ON enums."NAME" = N'someName'
        AND job1."jobType" = enums."VALUEID"
    INNER JOIN ( 
        select 0.0 as "value"
        union all 
        select 1.0 
    ) as slot
        ON ( slot."value" = 0 AND ( enums."VALUE" = N'setup' OR ( enums."VALUE" = N'normal' AND prevJob."id" IS NULL ) ) )
        OR ( slot."value" = 1 AND enums."VALUE" = N'normal' );

    DECLARE @PeggingRelations TABLE
    (
            "oprNum1"               INTEGER
            , "job1Id"              NVARCHAR( 100 )
            , "job1Type"            INT
            , "oprNum2"             INTEGER
            , "job2Id"              NVARCHAR( 100 )
            , "job2Type"            INT
            , "minimumDistance"     INT
            , "maximumDistance"     INT
            , "resourceLocked"      INT
            , "durationLocked"      INT
            , "slot1"               FLOAT
            , "slot2"               FLOAT
            , "color"               INT     
            , "origin"              NVARCHAR(50)
            , "partition" BIGINT
    );

    DECLARE @MinMax TABLE
    (
          "prodId"      NVARCHAR( 20 )
        , "maxOprNum"   INT
        , "minOprNum"   INT
    );

    INSERT INTO @MinMax
    SELECT 
          "prodId"      = "prodId"
        , "maxOprNum"   = MAX( "oprNum" ) 
        , "minOprNum"   = MIN( "oprNum" ) 
    FROM
        "dbo"."_company_job"
    GROUP BY 
          "prodId";

    INSERT INTO @PeggingRelations
    SELECT DISTINCT
        "oprNum1"           = Job1."oprNum"
        , "job1Id"          = Job1."id"
        , "job1Type"        = Job1."jobType"
        , "oprNum2"         = Job2."oprNum"
        , "job2Id"          = Job2."id"
        , "job2Type"        = Job2."jobType"
        , "minimumDistance" = 0
        , "maximumDistance" = 2147483647
        , "resourceLocked"  = CASE Job1."oprNum" WHEN Job2."oprNum" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        , "durationLocked"  = 0
        , "slot1"           = job1."OVERLAPFACTOR"
        , "slot2"           = 0.0
        , "color"           = 0x0000FFFF    
        , "origin"          = N'workorder'
        , "partition"       = Job1."partition"
    FROM
        "dbo"."REQTRANSCOV" AS Link
    INNER merge JOIN "dbo"."REQTRANS" AS Issuer
         ON Issuer."DATAAREAID"     = Link."DATAAREAID"
         AND Issuer."PARTITION" = Link."PARTITION"  
        AND Issuer."RECID"          = Link."ISSUERECID"
    INNER JOIN "dbo"."REQTRANS" AS Receiver
         ON Receiver."DATAAREAID"   = Link."DATAAREAID"
         AND Receiver."partition" = Link."partition"
        AND Receiver."recid"        = Link."RECEIPTRECID"
    INNER JOIN @MinMax AS IssuerMinOprNum
         ON IssuerMinOprNum."PRODID"        = Issuer."REFID"
    INNER JOIN @MinMax AS ReceiverMaxOprNum
         ON ReceiverMaxOprNum."PRODID"      = Receiver."REFID"
    INNER JOIN "dbo"."_company_job" AS Job2 
         ON Job2."prodId"           = Issuer."REFID"
        AND Job2."oprNum"           = IssuerMinOprNum."minOprNum"
        AND Job2."isFirst"      = 1
        AND Job2."oprPriority"  = 0
        AND Job2."partition" = Issuer."partition"
    INNER JOIN "dbo"."_company_job" AS Job1
         ON Job1."prodId"       = Receiver."REFID"
        AND Job1."isLast"       = 1
        AND Job1."sourceTable"  = N'PRODTABLE'
        and job1."partition" = Receiver."partition"
    WHERE  
        1 = 1
        AND Issuer."REFTYPE"    IN ( 9, 12 )
        AND Receiver."REFTYPE"  IN ( 9, 12 )
        AND Link."DATAAREAID" = N'company'

    INSERT INTO @Results
    (
          "id"
        , "oprNum1"
        , "job1Id"
        , "job1Type"
        , "oprNum2"
        , "job2Id"
        , "job2Type"
        , "minimumDistance"
        , "maximumDistance"
        , "resourceLocked"
        , "durationLocked"
        , "slot1"
        , "slot2"
        , "color"
        , "origin"      
        , "partition"
    )
    SELECT
          "id"              = "job1Id" + N'_' + "job2Id"
        , "oprNum1"
        , "job1Id"  
        , "job1Type"
        , "oprNum2"
        , "job2Id"  
        , "job2Type"        
        , "minimumDistance"
        , "maximumDistance"
        , "resourceLocked"
        , "durationLocked"
        , "slot1"
        , "slot2"
        , "color"
        , "origin"
        , "partition"
    FROM
        @PeggingRelations;

    INSERT INTO @Results 
    (
          "id"
        , "oprNum1"
        , "job1Id"
        , "job1Type"
        , "oprNum2"
        , "job2Id"
        , "job2Type"
        , "minimumDistance"
        , "maximumDistance"
        , "resourceLocked"
        , "durationLocked"
        , "slot1"
        , "slot2"
        , "color"
        , "origin"
        , "partition"
    )
    SELECT
          "id"              = Job1."id" + N'_' + Job2."id"
        , "oprNum1"         = Job1."oprNum"
        , "job1Id"          = Job1."id"
        , "job1Type"        = Job1."jobType"
        , "oprNum2"         = Job2."oprNum"
        , "job2Id"          = Job2."id"
        , "job2Type"        = Job2."jobType"
        , "minimumDistance" = 0
        , "maximumDistance" = 2147483647
        , "resourceLocked"  = CASE Job1."oprNum" WHEN Job2."oprNum" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        , "durationLocked"  = 0
        , "slot1"           = job1."OVERLAPFACTOR"
        , "slot2"           = 0.0
        , "color"           = 0x0000FFFF    
        , "origin"          = N'workorder'
        , "partition"       = Job1."partition"
    FROM 
        "dbo"."PRODBOM" AS PB
    INNER JOIN "dbo"."_company_job" AS Job1
         ON Job1."prodId"       = PB."INVENTREFID"
         and Job1."partition" = PB."partition"
        AND Job1."isLast"       = 1
        AND Job1."sourceTable"  = N'PRODTABLE'
        AND Job1."jobType"      = 4
    INNER JOIN "dbo"."_company_job" AS Job2
         ON Job2."prodId"       = PB."PRODID"
        AND Job2."oprNum"       = PB."OPRNUM"
        AND Job2."isFirst"      = 1
        and Job2."partition" = PB."partition"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @Results AS Rel
         ON Rel."job1Id"    = Job1."id"
        AND Rel."job2Id"    = Job2."id"
        AND Rel."slot1"     = job1."OVERLAPFACTOR"
        AND Rel."slot2"     = 0.0
        AND Rel."partition" = Job1."partition"
    WHERE 
        1 = 1
        AND PB."DATAAREAID" = N'company'
        AND PB."INVENTREFTYPE"  = 3
        AND Rel."Id" IS NULL
        AND Rel."partition" = Job1."partition";
```

Comment: Try adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to all the queries that `SELECT` from the table variables.

Comment: @MartinSmith Followed your hint. Runtime increased to 2:40 min.

Comment: You'll need to compare the execution plans for the @table and #table versions. Inserts to table variables can't use parallel plans might be one explanation. Or may be because the statistics available for #temp tables cause a better plan. In which case you may need to resort to hints to get desired join types and orders.